# Clip For GradientDrawable.setCornerRadii not working

Tags: android, view, android-view, cornerradius, android-gradient-drawable

I'm trying to create a view with custom radius but facing a problem when using GradientDrawable.setCornerRadii...
Line If i use Below code the view clips all the child view inside it

```
public void SetCornerRadius(View v,int Radius){
        GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
        shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        shape.setCornerRadius((int)Px2Dp(Radius));
        v.setBackground(shape);
        v.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);
        v.setClipToOutline(true);
    }
```

But if i use Below code for different corner radius then Clipping is not working as expected as child view goes outside parent view

```
public void SetDifferentCornerRadius(View v,int TopLeftRadius,int TopRightRadius,int BottomLeftRadius,int BottomRightRadius,String backgroundColor){
        GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)v;
        shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        shape.setColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
        shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { (int)Px2Dp(TopLeftRadius),(int)Px2Dp(TopLeftRadius),(int)Px2Dp(TopRightRadius),(int)Px2Dp(TopRightRadius),(int)Px2Dp(BottomRightRadius),(int)Px2Dp(BottomRightRadius),(int)Px2Dp(BottomLeftRadius),(int)Px2Dp(BottomLeftRadius)});
        v.setBackground(shape);
        v.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);
        v.setClipToOutline(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it doesn't work because `setClipToOutline` only works for the shapes below.

> Currently, only Outlines that can be represented as a rectangle, circle, or round rect support clipping.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline#canClip()